# Github README file special character in table of content link

Tags: github, readme

In README.md I have a 2 levels of section :

```
# Topic

Some text

## Foo & Bar

More text
```

I want to make a table of content which links to the Topic and Foo & Bar, I tried :

```
- [Topic](#Topic )
  * [Foo & Bar](#Foo-&-Bar)
```

The above "Topic" link works correctly, but the `Foo & Bar` doesn't link to the corresponding section. Where am I wrong?

Comment: "Where am I wrong?" - in not looking at the actual anchor that github generates from that heading, so you can copy/use that.

Comment: `the actual anchor that github generates` thank you, but I would look at that if I knew it. It would be nice if you could provide me a reference, I tried googling what is wrong before asking question here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write the link `#foo--bar` like:

```
- [Topic](#Topic )
  * [Foo & Bar](#foo--bar)
```

Which you can find out when you inspect the readme with the developer tools in the browser, it looks something like:

[image]

Comment: I am learning making README.md better. Could you please guide me a bit how to see the generated link to solve problems like this? For example, I have another issue with `:`

Comment: @user842225 I've update the answer. If you don't know how to open `developer tools` in your browser your favourite search engine will guide you to the right resource.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is clear to me now. Nice answer!

Comment: Excellent answer, plus the reasoning behind it. Thanks.